# If I have only an address IP, what I can put on the app domain?

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I'm using Facebook SDK and PHP. Everything works fine with my localhost. But when I want to try it with my router WiFi (on my public IP Address, to add the Facebook login), I am trying to put the IP address on URL and App Domain but there is a problem.

When I leave the field App Domain blank, it doesn't allow me to do so. So I am trying to put a domain name on the file "hosts" for the address IP, and put this name on the app domain, it's doesn't work!

I really don't know what to do.

Comment: Please show us your code. Since I can't fully understand what you are asking since the english isn't perfect, your code would probably help a lot to deduce the problem you are having.

Comment: You need a **Fully Qualified Domain Name** and not an IP Address. Anyone can use an IP Address and do mischievous things.

Comment: But I have to add the facebook login on a captive portal, how I can to this without the ip address?

Comment: Or well, there could be another way, say, add a domain name, point the domain name's A to the IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a **Fully Qualified Domain Name** and not an IP Address. Anyone can use an IP Address and do mischievous things.

The workaround would be registering a domain name and point the A of the domain or sub-domain to the IP Address.

You still need to make sure the following holds:

1. The IP Address is publicly accessible (at least by Facebook's servers).
2. The domain name or sub-domain should be a FQDN.

Also if you change your `hosts` file, it affects only your PC, and the world or Facebook servers do not know.

> ***Tip:*** You can get a free domain (search in Google for freenom) and they also provide free DNS Management as well. You can put your IP Address there and try.

Comment: deep down inside, we all have a bit of hacker in us it seems :)

Comment: @Webeng I completely agree. But why? `:P`

Comment: do you mean why do we have a bit of hacker in us or why do I bring it up?

Comment: Why did you bring it up here? :P

Comment: Kind of a hacky way to get access to facebooks SKD for php :P

Comment: Actually, I changed the file "hosts" on the router Wifi, it's okay for facebook app domain, but I can't access to the captive portal.  I will try your solution for get a free domain name. Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0):

It will not work on facebook, You need to have a domain name If you want to use the facebook API.

Comment: But I have to add the facebook login on a captive portal, how I can to this without the ip address?

Comment: @Aurélie You cannot use IP address, you need to have a domain.